# Get vk.com video "hash" value

Tags: php, vk

I want to get vk.com embed video link. So far, I can only get part of it.

"oid" and "id" are easy to get from API but i can't seem to figure out a method to get the "hash" value.

**Embed link:**

```
https://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=-31038184&id=456242753&hash=d79895b5c0835fc7
```

**Direct link:**

```
https://vk.com/video-31038184_456242753
```

I don't know how the Hash is generated and by which method I can get it since I can't find documentation about it in the API for videos.

Comment: You want to extract `hash` from string or understand how it is getting generated ?

Comment: How it's getting generated

Comment: Did you check their API documentation for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `video.get` API method. Hash will be present in `response.items[0].player`

Example request:

```
https://api.vk.com/method/video.get?owner_id=-31038184&videos=-31038184_456242753&v=5.131&access_token=...
```

Documentation [here](https://vk.com/dev/video.get)